# nextcloud from appstream is missing dependencies

Tags: dnf, nextcloud, appstream

I want to install nextcloud on (Oracle Linux 8 or CentOS 8) from appstream.

Is it broken or am I doing something wrong?

```
dnf module enable nextcloud:24

dnf module install nextcloud/default

Error: 
 Problem 1: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides php-pecl-imagick needed by nextcloud-24.0.3-1.module_el8+14920+386fda55.noarch
  - nothing provides php-pecl-memcached needed by nextcloud-24.0.3-1.module_el8+14920+386fda55.noarch
  - nothing provides php-pecl-redis5 needed by nextcloud-24.0.3-1.module_el8+14920+386fda55.noarch
  - nothing provides php-smbclient needed by nextcloud-24.0.3-1.module_el8+14920+386fda55.noarch
```

the same for nextcloud 23.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that RHEL does not package some of the required PHP modules to properly install the latest version of NextCloud.

According to the [NextCloud documentation for installing on RHEL/CentOS/Oracle 8](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/admin_manual/installation/example_centos.html) it appears that PHP is required to be installed from [Remi's RPM Repository](https://rpms.remirepo.net) as they do provide packages of the PHP modules missing from the RHEL repositories.

The following commands would be required after a fresh install of RHEL/CentOS/Oracle 8 to install NextCloud 24 from Appstream while using PHP 7.4 from Remi:

```
# get the Remi repository configuration for EL8 and install it
dnf install https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-8.rpm
# reset the current PHP `dnf` module
dnf module reset php
# install PHP 7.4 from Remi's repository
dnf module install php:remi-7.4
# enable NextCloud `dnf` module
dnf module enable nextcloud:24
# install NextCloud
dnf module install nextcloud/default
```

That should get NextCloud installed, then you can continue to configure it.

Since Remi offers all current versions of PHP, you should be able to use the `dnf` module `php:remi-8.0` or `php:remi-8.1` to satisfy the PHP dependencies of NextCloud if you want to upgrade from PHP 7.4.